# Use data source from a function (dynamic datasource) - Select2 v4

Tags: javascript, jquery-select2

In the previous versions one can easily get this done by:

```
someDynamicData=function(){
     //return some data...
}

$("#lga").select2({
    width: '100%',
    allowClear: false, placeholder: "--- please select ---",
    data: function () {
        return {results: someDynamicData, text: 'name'};
    }
});
```

I this dosen't work with the new select2 v4. How do I achieve this in the new select2 v4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that might be stocked as much as I am with select2 v4. I got a workaroud. Please note that I am some javascript guru and there might be some better way around this issue. For the time being this is rocking:

**Case study:** I have a chained select options which share from a list JSON Objects: here I am show only *Subject* and *Level* example just to keep it simple. When a Subject is selected I what to initialize the Level data source from the selected Subject's data source

```
function getDynamicData(){
    return [
       {"code": "ACC", "name": "ACCOUNTING", "levels": [
            {"id": 3, "name": "SS 1", "description": "Senior Secondary School 1", "type": "Standard", "resultTemplates": []},
        ....
        ]}
        ....
    ];
}    

$.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/data/array', 'select2/utils'],
    function (ArrayData, Utils) {
        function CustomData($element, options) {
            CustomData.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
        }

        Utils.Extend(CustomData, ArrayData);

        CustomData.prototype.query = function (params, callback) {
            subjects = getDynamicData();
            $.map(subjects, function (d) {//Required only when the object do not have either id/text
                d.id = d.code;
                d.text = d.name;
                return d;
            });
            callback({results: subjects});
        };

        $("#subjects").select2({
            width: '100%',
            dataAdapter: CustomData
        });
    }
);
```

[This works fine](https://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/Lq784sqh) but then I realized that I am repeating many things hence it is [time for cleanup](https://jsfiddle.net/Pauldic/Lq784sqh/2/])

```
//Added this function to a javascript file on my template (shared across pages)
function initMySelect2(myQuery, mySelector, props) {
    $.fn.select2.amd.require(['select2/data/array', 'select2/utils'],
        function (ArrayData, Utils) {
            function CustomData($element, options) {
                CustomData.__super__.constructor.call(this, $element, options);
            }

            Utils.Extend(CustomData, ArrayData);
            CustomData.prototype.query = myQuery;//Pass the query function as a parameter
            $(mySelector).select2(props(CustomData));//Initialise the select2 with the custom data
        }
    );
}

//Used this to initialize select2
initMySelect2(function (params, callback) {
        callback({results: getDynamicData()});
    },
    "#subjects",
    function (myCustomData) {
        return {
            width: '100%',
            placeholder: '---please select subjects ---',
            dataAdapter: myCustomData
        };
    }
);
```

Reference https://select2.github.io/announcements-4.0.html
I hope this will help someone out there.